# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List how to fix

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, exception

```
 List<Candidate> candidates = (List<Candidate>) session.createSQLQuery("select candidate.* from candidate inner join candidate_skill on candidate.id = candidate_skill.candidate_id inner join skill on candidate_skill.skill_id = skill.id where skill.id = 1");
```

And I see:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Query is correct. How to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot `.list()` at end of the query.

It should be something like

```
................skill.id where skill.id = 1").list();
```

Refer [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html) for more information.

Comment: Can You help get real List<Candidate>, now I get array of object, which consist of array of fields

Comment: @user2645679: You need to loop List<Object[]>, get Object[] and do lookup based on index, index 0 reporents first column data, index 1 represents second coulmns etc., populate that to Candidate Object.

Comment: is there no better solution?

Comment: @user2645679: Not I know of when you are using native SQL.

Comment: HQL can be helpfull for this situation?

Comment: @user2645679: If use HQL, yes then you can overcome this by passing Candidate as parameter. I would suggest read more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35150/discussion-between-user2645679-and-nambari)

Answer (score 2):

Query not returning any thing and you are trying to  assign it to List

You should do

```
 List<Candidate> candidates = (List<Candidate>) session.createSQLQuery
               ("select candidate.* from candidate inner join 
                    candidate_skill on candidate.id = candidate_skill.
                        candidate_id inner join skill on 
                  candidate_skill.skill_id = skill.id 
                                          where skill.id = 1").list();
```

[A simple native query example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/)

Comment: I think, you can help for write this query using HQL. I want to get List<Candidates>

Comment: Why query ,i would like suggest criteras..please have a look on criterias.